# Can I store firebase data & run the application functions in offline mode in React-native?

Tags: react-native

I found some tutorials about offline mode firebase for React-native but still I don't know how can I enable this thing in my application.

So, how can I store all recieved data and run the functions in offline mode?

Answer (score 0):

you can search on `persistence` in the firebase component you use and set it to `true`

an popular one is [react-native-firebase](https://invertase.io/react-native-firebase/)

and you can set this in it's [configuration-options](https://invertase.io/react-native-firebase/#/v2/usage?id=configuration-options)